# Modifying Paste to only allow values without having to right-click

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a macro that would help me be quicker to copy paste material. I often find myself copying a text or a number (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>) and when I want to paste it to a cell in Excel I need to right click and choose Past values.

I'll try to write a malfunctioning example of what I'm after:

```
Sub PasteValuesOrText()

Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
myString = DataObj.GetValue
ActiveCell.Value = myString

End Sub
```

Comment: Check the following article from @SiddharthRout website. http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/15/vba-excelallow-paste-special-only/

Answer (score 0):

This will at least let you double click to copy and is a start to you coding.

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Target.Copy
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something to paste special without a lot of extra clicking. The following macro will take something that is already copied and simply paste values in the selected cell.

One thing to note, is that by doing this you will lose undo capabilities.

```
Sub Paste_Values()
    Selection.PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, _
        Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```